# How to change Divi blog elements order?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi

I have experience with Wordpress but is my first time with Divi. Based on the client design, I need simple change. On the image below you could see block from the blog(a post list used on the homepage in my case)[image]

What I need to do is showing the date, category and title in a different order. Which is the best way to change this. I'm using a child theme and I tried to put the file `includes/builder/module/blog.php`  and edit it but I don't have any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the divi page builder ? If so, it might be possible in the settings of the section where your post is located (you can edit it directly from the front end editor).

Comment: not everything is possible inside divi builder. posted answer with code

Answer (score 0):

You have to move blog.php to correct folder of the child theme first:

includes/blog.php

After that, need to modify code, first at the top of the file:

```
require_once 'helpers/Overlay.php';
class ET_Builder_Module_Blog extends ET_Builder_Module_Type_PostBased {
```

Change to:

```
require_once 'helpers/Overlay.php';
class ET_Builder_Module_Blog extends ET_Builder_Module_Type_PostBased {
```

Set vb_support to "off"

Comment out line at the very bottom of the file:

```
new ET_Builder_Module_Blog();
```

And finally, activate new module in the functions.php of your child theme:

```
function custom_divi_blog_module() { 
   get_template_part( '/includes/Blog' ); 
   $dcfm = new custom_ET_Builder_Module_Blog(); 
   remove_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog' ); 
   add_shortcode( 'et_pb_blog', array( $dcfm, '_shortcode_callback' ) ); 
} 

add_action( 'et_builder_ready', 'divi_custom_blog_module' ); 

function custom_divi_blog_module( $classlist ) { 
  $classlist['et_pb_blog'] = array( 'classname' => 'custom_ET_Builder_Module_Blog',); 
  return $classlist; 
} 

add_filter( 'et_module_classes', 'divi_custom_blog_class' );
```

After that you can perform required modifications to layout and even add your own features :)